# how to add animation for core plot datalabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, core-plot

I want the effect when the user clicks the button. The data label in bar plot disappear in animation. Change alpha value from 1 to 0.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.hostingView.hostedGraph.allPlots firstObject].showLabels = showLabel;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
}
```

But the animation doesn't show. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIView` animations won't work since Core Plot is built on Core Animation layers. The list of data labels is private to the plot but they're displayed using Core Plot annotations. The plot's `annotations` property gives you an array of all annotations attached to the plot. Loop through the array and apply the desired animation to the `contentLayer` of each annotation. If you have other annotations on the plot, be sure to check to make sure you're only animating the data labels. Each `CPTLayer` has an `identifier` property you can use to identify the annotations you create.